# Angular UI Router child state params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular 1.x with Angular UI Router.
I'm looking for a way to bind parameters in child states like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parameters', {
        url: '/parametres',
        templateUrl: 'views/profile/profile.html',
        controller: 'profileCtrl'
    })
    .state('parameters.personal', {
        url: '/informations-personnelles',
        params: {tab: 'personal'}
    })
    .state('parameters.email', {
        url: '/mails',
        params: {tab: 'email'}
    })
    .state('parameters.password', {
        url: '/mot-de-passe',
        params: {tab: 'password'}
    });
```

When I try to access `/parametres/mot-de-passe`, my `tab` param returns `undefined` value like if it is not bind. I also tried to bind the `tab` param in the `parameters` state, but the param returns the value i'm binding in. Not the one in the good child state...

I'm looking for a way to instantly get the good `tab` param value when I open a child URL.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Child states inherit their parameters from their parents. So if you don't name them in the parent, they won't be in the child. In your case, it appears you have them in 3 child states, but not in the parent. Also, you said you tried to access a state that doesn't exist, which may be another reason you're not getting what you expect.

Comment: "So if you don't name them in the parent, they won't be in the child"
I'm confused about this answer... By using `parameters.` in child states, the parent is loaded (I can show the template, and the controller is loaded as well so...).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$state.params` instead of `$stateParams`. You should be able to access all of the parameters from the former.

The only caveat here is to make sure that your params have different names so you do not have clashes.

Answer (score 0):

It can be happen because in your parent controller you are passing some value but not resolving the same in parent controller.

so parent controller `$stateParams.someVal` if not exist in the child controller then it will throw undefined.
so you have to put the resolve property in the parent state like that :

```
 $stateProvider.state('contacts.detail', {
   url: '/contacts/:contactId',   
   controller: function($stateParams){
            $stateParams.contactId  //*** Exists! ***//
   },
   resolve:{
      contactId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
           return $stateParams.contactId;
           }]
   }
   }).state('contacts.detail.subitem', {
             url: '/item/:itemId', 
             controller: function($stateParams, contactId){
                 contactId //*** Exists! ***//
                 $stateParams.itemId //*** Exists! ***//  
          }
   })
```

something like above u need to do that

Please check it here :https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing